# how to show media content from contentful using gatsby

Tags: graphql, media, gatsby, contentful

Going through [Andrew Mead's gatsby tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t0vNu2fCCM&). I have my contentful model set up with a media field for the hero image. The rich text and text fields work fine. In my index page I want each post to show up with a thumbnail of the hero image. My graphql query looks like this, and you can see **heroImage** in there, which works fine in the graphql playground:

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allContentfulWork(sort: { fields: publishedDate, order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
            heroImage {
              file {
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

^^This works in graphql playground. And below in index.js I'm returning:

```
return (
    <Layout>
      <ul className={workStyles.indexPage}>
        {data.allContentfulWork.edges.map(edge => {
          return (
            <li>
              <Link to={`/work/${edge.node.slug}`}>
                <h3>{edge.node.title}</h3>
                {edge.node.publishedDate}
                <img src={edge.node.heroImage.file.url} />
              </Link>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  )
```

the issue is **{edge.node.heroImage.file.url}** returns an error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null`.

how can I embed that image?

Comment: Try inserting a `console.log(edge)` inside your `.map` function. What does the edge object look like? If it is undefined try `console.log(data)` before returning `Layout`. Do you get your data as in the graphQL playground?

Comment: I think the error happens because not all of them have a heroImage. so I did this:  {console.log( edge.node.heroImage.file  ?  "has hero image" : "has no hero image")} but that breaks it too.. I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null
'

Answer (score 0):

I think it was throwing an error because not all contentful posts had a heroImage. I added a ternary to see if {edge.node.heroImage.file.url} existed, but, that threw an error too I think because edge.node.heroImage didn't exist for some posts. So, here is what worked:

```
{edge.node.heroImage && (
    <img
         src={edge.node.heroImage.file.url}
         alt={edge.node.title}
    />
)}
```